# Partially specialize template member function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class which looks like the following:

```
template <template <class TypeT> class PoolT=pool_base>
struct pool_map
{
public:
  template <typename U> struct pool { typedef PoolT<U> type };

public:
  template <typename T, size_t S=sizeof(T)>
  T& get( size_t index );

private:
  pool<uint8_t>::type  pool8_;
  pool<uint16_t>::type pool16_;
  pool<uint32_t>::type pool32_;
  pool<uint64_t>::type pool64_;
};

template <template <class TypeT> class PoolT>
template <typename T, size_t S>
inline
T& pool_map<PoolT>::get( size_t index )
{
  // Default case
}

template <template <class TypeT> class PoolT>
template <typename T>
inline
T& pool_map<PoolT>::get<T,8>( size_t index )
{
  // Dispatch to pool8_
}

template <template <class TypeT> class PoolT>
template <typename T>
inline
T& pool_map<PoolT>::get<T,16>( size_t index )
{
  // Dispatch to pool16_
}

template <template <class TypeT> class PoolT>
template <typename T>
inline
T& pool_map<PoolT>::get<T,32>( size_t index )
{
  // Dispatch to pool32_
}
```

You obviously noticed that I wrote what would be possible in a wonderful and ideal world where default template parameters and partial specialization of template methods are possible (without specializing the entire class).

I would like to ear about advices to achieve the same effect, that is, being able to have a specialized method for each size S so that I can select the proper pool to use. I tried to add a `get_pool<size_t>` inside the pool_map, but almost the same problem happens: i can't specialize the inner class without specializing the outer one...

The only solution that comes to my mind, would be to use an outer `get_pool<size_t>` class that would take the pool_map as parameters an returns a reference to the `poolX_` member, but I would like to avoid it, since it does not seems to be "the real static way".

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one easy solution (maybe you didn't think about it), which is:

```
template <typename T>
T& pool_map<PoolT>::get( size_t index )
{
  if (sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT == 8) {
     // Dispatch to pool8_
  } else if (sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT == 16) {
     // Dispatch to pool16_
  } else if (...) {
     ...
  } else {
    // Default case
  }
}
```

But since this will maybe give you compilation errors (depending on what you put instead of "dispatch to ...") you could simply overload the get() function.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT == 8,T>::type&
    get( size_t index )
{
   ...
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT == 16,T>::type&
    get( size_t index )
{
   ...
}

etc.
```

The only problem is that the default implementation (if you need any) needs a condition like `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT != 8 && sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT != 16 && sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT != 32 && sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT != 64`

The last solution (the best one I'd say) would still to use a private class with a static function which you can specialize (what you said was not the "real static way")

Comment: I managed to solve it. Thanks for your very accurate and exhaustive answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is the use of `enable_if` and `disable_if` (normally) though I haven't tested it.

Another solution is to simply forward the implementation details to a helper:

```
namespace helper
{
  template <class T> struct getter { static void Do() {} };

  // specializations by type
}

template <class T>
T& pool_map<T>::get(size_t index) { return helper::getter<T>::Do(); }
```